# Improve 'Look Inside' view of the Kindle mobi eBook in Amazon

Tags: kindle, mobi

I want to improve the "Look Inside" view of the Kindle ebook.

When I click on the eBook Cover in Amazon, the "Look Inside" window appears. Although I have split the book into separate files at each page breaks, "Look Inside" appears as one page without any page breaks.

Kindly suggest how to add page breaks in "Look Inside" view too. So there will be page breaks for the title page, copyright page, part title page, chapter pages.

Comment: Is this on Amazon now? Would be helpful to take a peek myself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working as designed by Amazon. When they create the mobi package of files from your upload on KDP, one of the things they create is a .html version of the whole book - basically the entire book on one long scrolling page. I think this is used for the Look Inside feature. Look at some other major Kindle books and see if it's the same.